# Need Help in function open and write

Tags: python

I wrote a code that operates on a 9-digit numbers and the answer is a number.

My problem is ,I want to retrieve the numbers from a text file and store the answer against a 9-digit number in another file, but when the code runs Saves it to the next line.

Where's the coding problem?

An example of a 9-digit number: 324238577 and the program answer 2

I want to save this as 3242385772

Code is :

```py
    import os
    masir = os.getcwd()
    print (masir)
    with open ("code_melii.txt","r") as file:
        data = file.readlines()
        bad = 0
        good = 0

        for i in data:
            goodp = good +1
            good = goodp
            badp = bad +1
            bad = badp
            file_1  =open("code_melli_checked.txt","a+")
            code = str(i)

            a = code[0]
            a_1 = int(a) * 10

            b = code[1]
            b_1 =int (b) * 9

            c = code[2]
            c_1 = int(c) * 8

            e = code[3]
            e_1 =int (e) * 7

            f = code[4]
            f_1 = int(f) * 6

            g = code[5]
            g_1 = int(g) * 5

            h = code[6]
            h_1 = int(h) * 4

            z = code[7]
            z_1 = int(i) * 3

            j= code[8]
            j_1 = int(j) * 2

            som = (a_1+b_1+c_1+e_1+f_1+g_1+h_1+z_1+j_1)%11


            if som < 2:
                check_code = str(som)
                check_code2 = code+check_code
                print (check_code2)

    file_1.write(check_code2)
                print (good,"           good")

            elif som > 2:
                check_code = str(11-som)
                check_code2 = code+check_code


    file_1.write(check_code2)
                print (good,"           good")

            else:

                print (bad," bad")
                print ()
```

Comment: Notice you opened the file with the "a+" flag, which means that each write to the file would be appended to the end of the file. Also take note that you open the same file on each loop (and also not closing it), which means you might want to change your flow of the function.

Comment: Thanks for your help but problem not solved

Answer (score 0):

Just I did not get the question very well but I think your programing style can be improved.

```
        z = code[7]
        z_1 = int(i) * 3
```

Chnage to

```
        z = code[7]
        z_1 = int(z) * 3
```

And next time use better name ;) 
https://medium.com/better-programming/string-case-styles-camel-pascal-snake-and-kebab-case-981407998841

Comment: The problem with this code is that the answer is stored in line after the input code.